# Terraform error creating API Gateway Resource complains another resource with the same parent already has this name

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating an API Gateway resource called "lang":

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "lang" {
  path_part   = "lang"
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.api.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.id
}
```

Having successfully created the API, when running `terraform apply` subsequent times, I get this error:

```
Error: Error creating API Gateway Resource: ConflictException: Another resource with the same parent already has this name: lang
```

The resource block above is absolutely, definitely the only one with that name. I've googled enough on this to realise that terraform is complaining that the resource called "lang" already exists and can't be recreated. What I don't know is how to get it destroyed first.

I have tried adding this to my script:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.id
  stage_name    = var.envName
  
  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode(aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.body))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

...to no avail.

Should the `create_before_destroy` property not essentially destroy the API and cause it to be recreated or only the stage?

How can I make changes to the "lang" resource if the resource block can't do it? This seems a fundamental circular problem to me.

Comment: Why would the `lang` API resource (not TF resource), already exist? Did you create it manually using AWS console/cli/sdk?

Comment: Near the top I've said "when running terraform apply subsequent times". This means that it was created the first time I ran the apply. It appears that it cannot be changed on following apply's.

Comment: I hit this error when I had deployed my changes (on a branch), but they were overwritten (switching to main) leaving the API behind.  Manually deleting the API on AWS solved the problem and allowed TF to get to the next error

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, this was a late night typo...

I had (deliberately) copy-pasted the `resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "lang"` block and forgotten to rename the copy when going through and updating all the copies for their own purposes.